# Prove that $(1/n^n)\leq(1/n!)$ for every $n\geq1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

I want to know if my answer is correct:

1) For **n=1**: $ 1=1$  Correct! 
2) Let **n=k** is an inductive assumption which is correct: 
$$\frac{1}{k^k}\leq \frac{1}{k!}$$
3) For **n=k+1**, we should prove that:
$$\frac{1}{(k+1)^{k+1}}\leq \frac{1}{(k+1)!}$$
So,
$$\frac{1}{(k+1)!}=
\frac{1}{(k+1)k!}\geq 
\frac{1}{(k+1)k^k}\geq 
\frac{1}{(k+1)(k+1)^k}=
\frac{1}{(k+1)^{k+1}}$$

**It's correct also for $n=k+1$, so the inequality $1/(k+1)^{k+1}\leq1/(k+1)!$ is correct for every number $n\geq1$**

Comment: Hello, and welcome to MSE.  I don't see anything in particular wrong with your solution. Did you have any particular reason to think your answer may not be correct?

Comment: It's okay isn't it?

Comment: If by "okay" you mean is there anything wrong with it, I don't see any mistakes.

Comment: You are welcome for the confirmation.  However, this is a fairly minor point, but as you're asking for confirmation of accuracy, well I just noticed that your last part should have $k + 1$ replaced by $n$, plus you may wish to make it clear you're dealing with natural numbers. Thus, you may wish to have it end with "so the inequality $\frac{1}{n^n} \leq \frac{1}{n!}$ is correct for every natural number $n \ge 1$".

Comment: Yes, I know. I didn't write at the begining that we are dealing with natural numbers in this task. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: @Viktor - Welcome to MSE - Just so you are aware: When asking for confirmation of work it's best to add the 'Proof Verification' Tag. I will add it now for you.

Comment: The inequality says $n! \leq n^{n}$. Isn't this obvious since $n! =(1)(2)...(n) \leq (n)(n)...(n)=n^{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct! I see nothing wrong with it as far as I know about mathematical induction. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Please avoid posting just "You are correct"-like answers. They should be in the comments instead. To make this post into an answer, you could say that the OP is correct, then suggest an alternative solution to prove the inequality. For example, $n^n=n\cdot n\cdots n$ and $n!=n\cdot(n-1)\cdots1$, which means that...